# Get UTC offset from time zone name in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

How can I get UTC offset from time zone name in python?

For example: I have `Asia/Jerusalem` and I want to get `+0200`

Comment: with Python 3.9 you would use `datetime.datetime.now(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('Asia/Jerusalem')).utcoffset()`, not needing any third party libraries.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Because of DST (Daylight Saving Time), the result depends on the time of the year:

```
import datetime, pytz

datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem')).strftime('%z')

# returns '+0300' (because 'now' they have DST)


pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem').localize(datetime.datetime(2011,1,1)).strftime('%z')

# returns '+0200' (because in January they didn't have DST)
```

Comment: `pytz.timezone("Etc/GMT-5").localize(datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1)).strftime("%z")` returns "+0500", not "-0500"

Comment: @404usernamenotfound I think that in programmatical contexts GMT-5 actually means +0500 and translated to human language it means "GMT+5". Confusing? Yes.

Comment: @JannePaalijarvi No, the positive ones are named `Etc/GMT+n` in my list. There are also negative `Etc/GMT-n` zones. I got it working, but not using pytz.

Comment: Etc/GMT-5 => +0500 is valid :
root@am335x-evm:~# timedatectl 
               Local time: Fri 2023-08-18 10:46:24 +05
           Universal time: Fri 2023-08-18 05:46:24 UTC
                 RTC time: Fri 2023-08-18 05:46:25
                Time zone: Etc/GMT-5 (+05, +0500)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no

Answer (score 84):

Have you tried using the [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) project and the [`utcoffset` method](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#tzinfo-api)?

e.g.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> pacific_now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
>>> pacific_now.utcoffset().total_seconds()/60/60
-7.0
```

Comment: BTW, the Ubuntu package for pytz is python-tz.

Comment: I don't dare downvote him, but utcoffset is a method on datetime objects, as best I can tell, so it doesn't provide this from a timezone name.

Comment: @Tom: It's *also* available on `tzinfo` objects though. See http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#tzinfo-api

Comment: @jon-skeet Thanks, I missed that. Are we officially beefing now?

Comment: Beware that if the server is using a timezone other than the one given than this produces incorrect results during the daylight savings time switch over. The datetime passed to `timezone.utcoffset()` is assumed to be local to that time zone and will fail if passed either the hour that daylight savings begins or ends. `datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')).utcoffset().total_seconds() / 60 / 60` is a better approach.

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa: Would just changing `today = datetime.datetime.now()` into `today = datetime.datetime.utcnow()` not work? Doesn't that value "know" that it's in UTC?

Comment: @jon-skeet You end up with the same result if you use `.utcnow()` instead of `.now()` because `pytz.timezone.utcoffset()` interprets whatever is passed to it as being in that time zone. Furthermore I'd bet most servers use UTC as their time zone so `.now()` and `.utcnow()` will be the exact same thing. I did try `today = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` but this fails with `ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)`.

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa: Urgh. That's unfortunate. So should your earlier suggestion actually just use `datetime.datetime.utcnow().astimezone(pytz.timezone('US‌​/Pacific')).utcoffse‌​t()`? (I know from experience that it's hard to design a date/time API, but I do wish the existing ones would be better documented...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Heh, that fails because you end up with a datetime that is unbound to a time zone and pytz raises: `ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime`. A quicker way that does work is `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')).utcoffset()`

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa: Ah joy. That's what you get when you use a single type for multiple things :( Have edited my answer based on your comments.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue while converting to UTC timestamp from python datetime object. My datetime was timezone agnostic (very naive) and as such `astimezone` would not work.

To mitigate the issue, I made my datetime object timezone aware and then used the above magic.

```
import pytz
system_tz = pytz.timezone(constants.TIME_ZONE)
localized_time = system_tz.localize(time_of_meeting)
fmt = "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S" + 'Z'
return localized_time.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime(fmt)
```

Here, `constants.TIME_ZONE` is where I had the default timezone of my persisted objects.

Hope this helps someone attempting to convert python datetime objects to UTC. Once converted, format any way you please.

Answer (score 2):

Another perspectife from @Jon Skeet [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5537943/11671779), assuming you already have `datetime.datetime` object, for example `day = datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 24)`:

```
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")

import datetime
day = datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 24)

offset = tz.utcoffset(day)/3600
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get UTC Offset as an integer:

```
import datetime
import pytz
from tzwhere import tzwhere

tzwhere = tzwhere.tzwhere()
timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem')
offSet_str = str(timezone.utcoffset(datetime.datetime.now()))
if offSet_str[0] != '-':
    offSet = int(offSet_str[0])
else:
    offSet = int(offSet_str[8] + offSet_str[9]) - 24

print(offSet)
```

Jon Skeet has a faster method

Comment: Note that UTC offset is not always an integer. Some timezones have 45min offset. Sigh...