# Python time zone display

Tags: python, time, zone

I'm not sure if this is possible but here's the question:

In python, is it possible to get a variable that shows the timezone relative to UTC time? For example, EST would be shown as -5, PST as -8.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [get UTC offset from time zone name in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537876/get-utc-offset-from-time-zone-name-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking exactly. Hope this may help!,You can use the datetime module . Adapted from http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.fromutc

from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime

```
class FixedOffset(tzinfo):
    def __init__(self, offset):
        self.__offset = timedelta(hours=offset)
        self.__dst = timedelta(hours=offset-1)
        self.__name = ''

def utcoffset(self, dt):
    return self.__offset

def tzname(self, dt):
    return self.__name

def dst(self, dt):
    return self.__dst

print datetime.now()
print datetime.now(FixedOffset(9))
```

Gives:

```
 2011-03-12 00:28:32.214000
 2011-03-12 14:28:32.215000+09:00
```

Comment: If you are satisfied,accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip times with timezones very easy using the `parsedate_tz` function from [email.utils](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate_tz).

```
from email.utils import parsedate_tz
import time

datetuple = parsedate_tz('Mon 4 jun 2012 12:34:56 +0700')
print datetuple
print '%s; offset: %s' % (time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', datetuple[:9]),
                          datetuple[9] / 3600.0)
```