# How to python logger format

Tags: python, logging, timestamp

I have python **2.7.5(linux)** and **2.7.12(anaconda, windows)** installed.
My logger looks like:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter( %(w)s - %(k)s - %(v)s',
                                  datefmt='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')
```

Linux:

```
- 10/May/2017:07:15:36 +0000 -
```

Windows(anaconda)

```
- 10/May/2017:16:23:15 Central Europe Daylight Time -
```

Anybody has an idea how to get rid of **"Central Europe Daylight Time"**
and have **+0000** instead ????

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem isn't with your code. Unfortunately the libraries under Windows don't support `%z` flag, and Python relies on those libraries.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#id2):

> The use of %Z is now deprecated, but the %z escape that expands to the preferred hour/minute offset is not supported by all ANSI C libraries.

Comment: Is there possibly any work around that I can apply ?

Comment: You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187488/python-strftime-utc-offset-not-working-as-expected-in-windows/26369814#26369814