# How can I convert IANA time zone name to UTC offset at present in Ubuntu C/C++

Tags: c++, c, c++11, ubuntu-14.04, timezone-offset

In Python or Java you can get the UTC offset (at present time) given the IANA name of the timezone ("America/Los_Angeles" for instance).  See [Get UTC offset from time zone name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537876/get-utc-offset-from-time-zone-name-in-python) for example.

How can you do the same using C/C++ on Ubuntu 14.04?

**EDIT**: Preferably in a thread-safe way (no environment variables).

Comment: Thread-safe!  You don't ask for much, do you? :-) Unfortunately the standard C/Unix functions are dreadfully thread-unsafe, because the defined way to ask for a different timezone is to, yes, set the `TZ` environment variable.  There are BSD extensions `tzalloc` and `localtime_tz` which fix this, but for some reason they've never gained much traction.  See my updated answer for some info.

Comment: For the life of me I cannot understand why are those functions (or similar) not in a C++ standard.  Both Python and Java have them as one-liners.  So does boost.  We live in a global world and global-local time calculation is a bread and butter.  Is that really too much to ask for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You alluded to this fact, but it's important to note that the offset between UTC and the time in a time zone is not necessarily constant.  If the time zone performs daylight saving (summer) time adjustments, the offset will vary depending on the time of year.

One way to find the offset is to take the time you're interested in, hand it to the `localtime()` function, then look at the `tm_gmtoff` field.  Do this with the `TZ` environment variable set to the zone name you're interested in.  Here's an example that does so for the current time:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    setenv("TZ", "America/Los_Angeles", 1);
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tmp = localtime(&t);
    printf("%ld\n", tmp->tm_gmtoff);
}
```

At the moment this prints -25200, indicating that Los Angeles is 25200 seconds, or 420 minutes, or 7 hours west of Greenwich.  But next week (actually tomorrow) the U.S goes off of DST, at which point this code will start printing -28800.

This isn't guaranteed to work, since the `tm_gmtoff` field is not portable.  But I believe all versions of Linux will have it.  (You might have to compile with `-D_BSD_SOURCE` or something, or refer to the field as `__tm_gmtoff`.  But in my experience it tends to work by default, as plain `tm_gmtoff`.)

The other way is to go back and forth with `gmtime` and `mktime`, as described in Sam Varshavchik's answer.

---

Addendum: You asked about not using environment variables. There is a way, but unfortunately it's even less standard.  There are BSD functions `tzalloc` and `localtime_rz` which do the job, but they do not exist on Linux.  Here's how the code looks:

```
    timezone_t tz = tzalloc("America/Los_Angeles");
    if(tz == NULL) return 1;
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm, *tmp = localtime_rz(tz, &t, &tm);
    printf("%ld\n", tmp->tm_gmtoff);
```

For me this prints -28800 (because PDT fell back to PST just a few minutes ago).

If you had it, you could also use `localtime_rz` along with `mktime` in Sam Varshavchik's answer.  And of course Howard Hinnant's library is pretty obviously thread-safe, not requiring mucking with `TZ` at all.

EDIT (OP):  The code for `localtime_rz` and `tzalloc` can be downloaded from https://www.iana.org/time-zones and works on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: `tm_gmtoff` is defined only on BSD and System V. The question is about Linux. There is no `tm_gmtoff` in Linux.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Every version of Linux I've used, including the Ubuntu system where I just compiled and tested the code I posted, has it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Read down to the Notes section.

Comment: Was just about to post the same. On the _actual_ manpage on my 16.04 box it clearly lists the two fields `tm_gmtoff` and `tm_zone` as being a glibc extension present if `_BSD_SOURCE` is set.

Comment: They're massively useful fields.  You can't do serious date/time programming without them. Every system *should* (IMHO) have them.  But, alas, they're still not Standard.  And if you don't have `tm_gmtoff`, or if you don't want to risk nonportability by using it, you can also use Sam's answer, which is a fine technique which I've used, too.

Comment: Is there a way to not use environment variables?  I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @SteveSummit: worth mentioning that the code for those functions can be downloaded from IANA itself: https://www.iana.org/time-zones which can be built for any POSIX (definitely Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

You could use this [free open source C++11/14 library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) to do it like this:

```
#include "chrono_io.h"
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto zt = make_zoned("America/Los_Angeles", system_clock::now());
    std::cout << zt.get_info().offset << '\n';
}
```

This currently outputs:

```
-25200s
```

Or you could format it differently like this:

```
    std::cout << make_time(zt.get_info().offset) << '\n';
```

which currently outputs:

```
-07:00:00
```

The factory function `make_zoned` creates a `zoned_time` using the IANA name "America/Los_Angeles" and the current time from `std::chrono::system_clock`.  A `zoned_time` has a [member getter to get the information](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#zoned_time) about the timezone *at that time*.  The information is a type called [`sys_info`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#sys_info) which contains all kinds of useful information, including the current UTC offset.

The UTC offset is stored as a `std::chrono::seconds`.  The header `"chrono_io.h"` will format `durations` for streaming.  Or the [`make_time`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#_41) utility can be used to format the duration into `hh:mm:ss`.

The program above is thread-safe.  You don't have to worry about some other process changing TZ out from under you, or changing the current time zone of the computer in any other way.  If you *want* information about the current time zone, that is available too, just use `current_zone()` in place of `"America/Los_Angeles"`.

If you wanted to explore other times, that is just as easy.  For example beginning at Nov/6/2016 at 2am local time:

```
    auto zt = make_zoned("America/Los_Angeles", local_days{nov/6/2016} + 2h);
```

The output changes to:

```
-28800s
-08:00:00
```

More information about this library was presented at Cppcon 2016 and can be viewed here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vwd3pduVGKY

Comment: Is it possible to use the _already installed_ IANA database files on Ubuntu?  This seems to require curl to pull from IANA etc.  What if I don't have a network?

Also:
`
ubuntu@ip-128-10-6-241:~/hhdate$ g++ -std=c++11 gmtoff.c  date/tz.cpp -I date -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl
ubuntu@ip-128-10-6-241:~/hhdate$ ./a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Timezone database version "2016i" did not install correctly to "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/tzdata"
Aborted (core dumped)
`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Howard's library, but it certainly ought to be possible to use it with the already-installed tzdata files.

Comment: @AndreySavov:  See https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation for how to configure the installation to not require curl (`-DHAS_REMOTE_API=0`).  In this case you will need to install the IANA database yourself.  The link is given in the installation instructions.  You want the "data only" file.  You can customize where you want to install it with `INSTALL` as described in the instructions.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: I am not seeing how to configure your code to take anything other than the IANA gzip file.  Linux has the DBs installed already under `/usr/share` and I would like to use that instead.

Comment: @AndreySavov:  Sorry, this library can't do that at this time.  The IANA database will consume about 945Kb of disk space and will be as up-to-date as you keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gmtime()`, first, to convert the current epoch time into UTC time, then use `mktime()` to recalculate the epoch time, then compare the result to the real epoch time.

`gmtime()` calculates the `struct tm` in UTC, while `mktime()` assumes that the `struct tm` represents the current local calendar time. So, by making this round-about calculation, you indirectly figure out the current timezone offset.

Note that `mktime()` can return an error if `struct tm` cannot be convert to epoch time, which will happen during certain transitions between standard time and alternate time. It's up to you to figure out what that means, in your case.

The recipe looks something like this:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *tmp = gmtime(&t);
time_t t2 = mktime(tmp);
int offset = t - t2;
```

See [the documentation of these library functions](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/ctime.3.html) for more information.

To use a specific time zone, either set the `TZ` environment variable, or you can try using `localtime_rz` as in Steve Summit's answer.  As mentioned, beware that `mktime` can sometimes return -1 for unconvertible times.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  My question is about getting the UTC offset of a _specific IANA timezone_, not my local one.

Could you please post code?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of updating Sam's answer (hope he doesn't mind).